# How to solve ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 after DELETE in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I used `model.setRowCount(0);` to refresh the table which works well but when I am updating/deleting data, I am encountering a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` .

```
private void fillTable() {
    try {
        model.setRowCount(0); // model is defaultdatamodel
        sql = "Select * from tbphonebook";
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); //driver already declared
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, uid, pwd); //con is Connection
        st = con.createStatement(); //st is statement
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql); //rs is resultSet

        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getString("id");
            fnam = rs.getString("firstname");
            lnam = rs.getString("lastname");
            add = rs.getString("address");
            cp = rs.getString("cp");

            model.addRow(new Object[]{id, fnam, lnam, add, cp});
            i++;

            if (i < 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No record \nfound!", "warning", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Here is my code for delete query

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    if (ae.getSource() == delete) {

        sql = "delete from tbphonebook where id='" + in + "'";

        if ( !"".equals(ids.getText())) {
            int ch = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "You are about to delete this contact. \n Do you wish to continue?","Warning!",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,null,null,null);
            if (ch == 0) {
                try {

                    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, uid, pwd);
                    st = con.createStatement();
                    st.executeUpdate(sql);
                    model.fireTableDataChanged();
                    con.close();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contact Deleted!!!", "Confirmation", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    clearFields(); // clear all text fields
                    fillTable();

                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose a contact then continue", "Nothing to delete", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "delete code" doesn't show how you update the TableModel anywhere. Just because you remove a row from the database does not mean the model is updated automatically. I would expect you need code like: `model.removeRow(...);`.

Comment: @camickr, i've updated my question. after the delete query, i call fillTable(); this works perfectly in the insert query, but commits error in delete. thanks.

Comment: You should NOT be using `model.fireTableDataChanged()`. The TableModel will invoke the appropriate fireXXX method when you invoke the setRowCount() and addRow(...) methods of the DefaultTableModel.

Comment: right! thanks. but even without it, I still receive the same error.  Or is my whole code not right?

Comment: If the fillTable() method works the first time, I'm not sure why it doesn't work the next time. The code looks reasonable. You haven't told us which statement is causing the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so I can't guess what is different.